# How to open and close a view by click on button in android

Tags: android, textview, click

I have some `buttons`and `textview`(textviews are below button). I want to show `textview`by click on `button`. That's mean when I still did not click on `button`, so `textview` should be closed(no hidden), without the use of visibility property. Like the picture below:

[image]

what do you suggest??

Comment: What do you mean without the visibility property?

Comment: you could use [ViewGroup.addView() and ViewGroup.removeView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Comment: in the android properties there is something called visibility that can select gone or visible or invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm. If I understood correctly, you will need something like this:

```
   public void onClick(View cview) throws IOException {
        switch (cview.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                //hide
                textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                //show
                textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
   }
```

Comment: yes but i said in my question, i don't want to use from this method. any way thank you.

Comment: Then you can choose to answer as true.

Answer (score 3):

One implementation would be to create, for each button, a translation animation for the others to use ( so that room would be created for the respective textview)
So you would press button1 and all the others would slide down .
Example, for button1:

```
private TranslateAnimation translateDown= new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,200);
translateDown.setDuration(300);
translateDown.setFillAfter(true);


private TranslateAnimation translateUp= new TranslateAnimation(0,0,200,0);
translateDown.setDuration(300);
translateDown.setFillAfter(true);

button1.onClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(textView1.isHidden(){
                button2.startAnimation(translateDown);
                button3.startAnimation(translateDown);
                button4.startAnimation(translateDown);
               textView1.show();
            }
            else{
                textView1.hide();
                button2.startAnimation(translateUp);
                button3.startAnimation(translateUp);
                button4.startAnimation(translateUp);                   
             }


        });
```

The same translation can be use for all cases ( the same amount of space must be created )

Comment: i don't understand. why did you use the button 2,3,4 in button 1 command??  in the your code translateFabDown is translateDown !!

Comment: If you click on button1, all of the others will go down, so that room will be made for the textView

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use the Visibility property.

But if you want to collapse the content, just set the height property of the TextView to 0 in the onClick event. That can do the trick for you.

```
    TextView test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    test.setHeight(0);
```